# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'password_reset_done' not found. 'password_reset_done' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-forms

I want to obtain the password_reset_done page when user has forgotten the password or username.On the login page there is a link written "forgot password or username", when a user clicks that link he will be directed to the password_reset page where an email address is entered.After the user has entered the email,he is supposed to be directed to the password_reset_done page but the above error pops out

My urls.py file looks like this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from app1.views import profile, welcome_view



urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include(('django.contrib.auth.urls', 'auth'), namespace='accounts')),
    path('accounts/profile/', profile, name ='profile'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.welcome_view, name ="welcome_view"),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing about Django's password management views is , they play by the rules of namespaces. That's why you have a namespace='accounts' in your urls.py file, right? So when you want to go to the password_reset_done view, Django is looking for it inside this namespace.

That error is Django basically saying, "I'm sorry , but I have no idea where this 'password_reset_done' place is." What you gotta do is tell Django exactly where to look.

Try changing your references to password_reset_done to 'accounts:password_reset_done'. This way, Django will know to look for it in the 'accounts' namespace, and will lead the users right where they should go. You know , like a top-notch GPS system.

If you're still having trouble , make sure you've got the Django auth URLs included in your main urls.py file. Your urls.py should look something like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path , include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls) ,
    path('accounts/' , include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),  # Here's where Django's auth views live
    path('', include('app1.urls')) ,  # Then you include your app's URLs here
]
```

In your app's urls.py (for example app1.urls.py) , you should include the path to your view:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import profile , welcome_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/profile/', profile , name='profile'),
    path('', welcome_view, name='welcome_view') ,
]
```

Comment: When l want to use the @login_required operator from django.contrib.auth.decorators your above codes are not responding